# Bashing redirecting output to a program

Tags: bash, scripting

Why isn't it reading the text file. What's a better way here is my code.
I am trying to read a line using for but it doesnt seem to work

```
if [[ "$#" -ne 1 ]]
then
    writeusage
    exit
fi
your_path=../file/test1
test_path=../../public/test1
file_input="$1"
while read -r line
do
   args+="$line"
done < "$file_input"
# Redirect the output to a file named text
$test_path > correctanswer 2>&1
# Redirect your output to a file named text2
$your_path > youranswer 2>&1
# diff the solutions
diff correctanswer youranswer
```

Comment: FYI, all-upper-case variable names are only conventional for environment variables and builtins; for process-local variables, consider using all-lower-case names to avoid potential namespace conflicts.

Comment: Also, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 -- `$YOUR_PATH$args` is pretty much broken-by-definition.

Comment: Hmm I see thanks for the tips do you know why I am running into the new problem?

Comment: If you want one line per argument, initialize with `args=()`, append with `args+=( "$line" )`, and invoke with `"$your_path" "${args[@]}"`. Note that this doesn't allow you to have arguments containing literal newlines -- if you wanted a file format that allowed any and every possible argument to be represented, you'd need to use NUL delimiters to separate your arguments rather than newline delimiters.

Comment: This question is one of a sequence of closely related if not duplicate questions: [SO 23282867](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23282867), [SO 23281913](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23281913), [SO 23280857](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280857), [SO 23280484](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280484).

Answer (score 1):

```
(( $# == 1 )) || { writeusage; exit 1; }

your_path=../file/test1
test_path=../../public/test1
file_input="$1"

# for bash older than 4.x
while read -r line; do
   args+=( "$line" )
done < "$file_input"

## ...for newer bash, you could do this instead:
# readarray -t args <"$file_input"

# Redirect the output to a file named text
"$test_path" "${args[@]}" > correctanswer 2>&1
# Redirect your output to a file named text2
"$your_path" "${args[@]}" > youranswer 2>&1
# diff the solutions
diff correctanswer youranswer
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your for loop to:

```
while read -r line
do
   args+="$line"
done < "$FILE_INPUT"
```

Comment: Could you explain what mine is doing?

Comment: @user3281743, no, that's not easy to explain, because what yours is doing depends heavily on the contents of the file, and also on your filesystem (for instance, if anything inside the file could be interpreted as a glob that applies to your local filesystem, that would change things).

Comment: Hmm now I am getting error of in the lines
$TEST_PATH$args >> correctanswer 2>&1
# Redirect your output to a file named text2
$YOUR_PATH$args >> youranswer 2>&1 
saying no such file or directory
my $TEST_PATH=../../test
but it says it can't find ../../test9
why is it adding a 9 at the end?

Comment: Your script has quite a few issues. Can you tell me what is `$TEST_PATH$args` doing?

Comment: I actually I don't know, I just saw an example and somewhat copied it, but what I would like to achieve is in that path direct the output of another out into that program

Comment: But now `$args` variable is not being used any where.

Comment: yeah I am unsure how to use it to put it in my program as an argument.