# Redirecting arguments into a program (BASH)

Tags: bash, scripting, piping

I am fairly new to bash scripting and a part I am stuck on is after 
    `done< "$file_input"`
What I am trying to achieve is when I run the program ./test  inside the testfile contains
the numbers 15 14 90 22 and the program is going to take those numbers as the arguments and run it, but I am quite unsure how to do that. Am I going in the correct direction?
Thanks for any help

```
if [[ "$#" -ne 1 ]]
then
    writeusage
    exit
fi
your_path=../file/test
test_path=../../public/test
file_input="$1"
while read -r line
do
   args+="$line"
done < "$file_input"
```

----------------- unsure how to redirect the arguments in a text file into my program and then put the result in a file named correctanswer and diff them

```
# Redirect the output to a file named text
$test_path > correctanswer 2>&1
# Redirect your output to a file named text2
$your_path > youranswer 2>&1   
# diff the solutions
diff correctanswer youranswer
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bashing redirecting output to a program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280484/bashing-redirecting-output-to-a-program)

Comment: I am asking a new question because that was a different question before.

Comment: This question is one of a sequence of closely related if not duplicate questions: [SO 23282867](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23282867), [SO 23281913](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23281913), [SO 23280857](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280857), [SO 23280484](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280484).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(< file)` to read a file into a variable. Using it unquoted afterwards will cause the contents to be passed as multiple arguments.

```
your_path=../file/test
test_path=../../public/test
file_input="$1"
contents=$(< "$file_input")

"$test_path" $contents > correctanswer 2>&1
"$your_path" $contents > youransweranswer 2>&1

diff correctanswer youranswer
```

This can more succinctly be written using process substitution:

```
diff <(../../public/test $(< "$1")) <(../file/test $(< "$1"))
```

Comment: what happens if i have multiple lines in the testfile for example I want to test the arguments 5 10 15 20 and 7 8 15 14

Comment: If it contains `5`, `10`, `15`, `20` on separate lines, the command will be called with the four arguments `5`, `10`, `15`, `20`.