# Reading multiple lines to redirect

Tags: bash, scripting

currently I have a file named testcase and inside that file has 5 10 15 14 on line one and
10 13 18 22 on line two

I am trying to bash script to take those two inputs line by line to test into a program. I have the while loop comment out but I feel like that is going in the right direction. 
**I was also wondering if is possible to know if I diff two files and they are the same return true or something like that** because I dont now if `[["$youranswer" == "$correctanswer"]]` is working the way I wanted to. I wanted to check if two contents inside the files are the same then do a certain command

```
#while read -r line
#do
#       args+=$"line"
#done < "$file_input"

# Read contents in the file
contents=$(< "$file_input")
# Display output of the test file
"$test_path" $contents > correctanswer 2>&1
# Display output of your file
"$your_path" $contents > youranswer 2>&1
# diff the solutions
if [ "$correctanswer" == "$youranswer" ]
then
         echo "The two outputs were exactly the same "
 else
         echo "$divider"
         echo "The two outputs were different "
         diff youranswer correctanswer
         echo "Do you wish to see the ouputs side-by-side?"
         select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
                 case $yn in
                         Yes ) echo "LEFT: Your Output   RIGHT: Solution Output"
                               sleep 1
                               vimdiff youranswer correctanswer; break;;
                         No ) exit;;
                 esac
        done
fi
```

Comment: This question is one of a sequence of closely related if not duplicate questions: [SO 23282867](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23282867), [SO 23281913](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23281913), [SO 23280857](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280857), [SO 23280484](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280484).

Answer (score 1):

From the `diff(1)` man page:

> Exit status is 0
>          if inputs are the same, 1 if different, 2 if trouble.

```
if diff -q file1 file2 &> /dev/null
  echo same
else
  echo different
fi
```

**EDIT:**

But if you *insist* on reading from more than one file at a time... don't.

```
while read -d '\t' correctanswer youranswer
do
   ...
done < <(paste correctfile yourfile)
```

Comment: @KRUKUSA: "I was also wondering if is possible to know if I diff two files and they are the same return true or something like that..."

Comment: Yes, do you by anychance know how to read from multiple lines?