# Reading each line as argument in bash

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, compilation, command

I am trying to learn bashing. I am trying to run ./test testcase
the file in test case has the arguments 9 11 22 13, 32 35 32 16 on the next line and so on
My program takes 4 arguments. Right now if testcase has one line of arguments i.e 3 5 6 7 it works fine, but when there is more than 2 it can't run the program properly. I know I need a while loop to read each line of the file, but I am stuck here. If someone could help me it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.
I've asked this question here before, I don't know if everyone is too busy or don't know how. Thanks again

```
your_path=../test/test
test_path=../../public/test    
file_input="$1"
#while read -r line; do
#done < "$file_input"

# Read contents in the file
contents=$(< "$file_input")
# Display output of the test file
"$test_path" $contents > correctanswer 2>&1
# Display output of your file
"$your_path" $contents > youranswer 2>&1
diff the solutions
diff correctanswer youranswer > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "The two outputs were exactly the same "
else
  echo "$divider"
  echo "The two outputs were different "
  diff youranswer correctanswer
  echo "Do you wish to see the ouputs side-by-side?"
      select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
      case $yn in
         Yes ) echo "LEFT: Your Output   RIGHT: Solution Output"
               sleep 1
               vimdiff youranswer correctanswer; break;;
         No ) exit;;
      esac
      done
fi
```

Comment: This question is one of a sequence of closely related if not duplicate questions: [SO 23282867](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23282867), [SO 23281913](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23281913), [SO 23280857](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280857), [SO 23280484](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280484).

Answer (score 1):

I would normally use a construct similar to the following (applying to your example). Note that the only change your need to make is the `cat $file | (while read l; do` and then `done)` that closes the cycle. The body of the cycle is exactly your code with exception that `contents` is replaced with `l` (line read). Parenthesis around the cycle actually launch another instance of the shell where while is executed and its `stdin` is set to be fed from `cat`.

```
your_path=../test/test
test_path=../../public/test    
file_input="$1"

exec 3< $file_input
while read -u 3 l; do
# do your per-test diffs and outputs here
# variable $l will contain one line of $file_input
    # Display output of the test file
    "$test_path" $l > correctanswer 2>&1
    # Display output of your file
    "$your_path" $l > youranswer 2>&1
    # diff the solutions
    diff correctanswer youranswer > /dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
      echo "The two outputs were exactly the same "
    else
      echo "$divider"
      echo "The two outputs were different "
      diff youranswer correctanswer
      echo "Do you wish to see the ouputs side-by-side?"
          select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
          case $yn in
             Yes ) echo "LEFT: Your Output   RIGHT: Solution Output"
                   sleep 1
                   vimdiff youranswer correctanswer; break;;
             No ) exit;;
          esac
          done
    fi

done
```

Comment: This sort of worked but it won't let me enter Yes or No after it goes into the else

Comment: Right. It's the same `stdin` that you're using. So instead of the entire `cat $file_input | (while read l; do` construct use the following: `exec 3< $file_input; while read -u 3 l; do` and also remove parenthesis after `done` at the end.

Comment: It still has the same problem for example if I run ./test testcase and testcase has 2 lines of 4 arguments, it doesn't run one by one.
Also the input is not right, it's not even taking it as arguments because the compiler is giving me usage problem. in the testcase file i have 4 ints 5 4 15 32 and my program takes 4 ints. Usually i run it by using ./program 5 4 15 32 and it would add them but it's giving me a usage problem.

Comment: @user3281743: you'll have to show us the output from `bash -x yourscript datafile`.  You also need to identify which version of Bash you are using and the environment you're using it in. This answer is basically the same as mine, and I've demonstrated that it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it like this:

```
your_path=../test/test
test_path=../../public/test    
file_input="$1"
while read -r -u 3 contents
do
    # Display output of the test file
    "$test_path" $contents > correctanswer 2>&1
    # Display output of your file
    "$your_path" $contents > youranswer 2>&1
    # diff the solutions
    diff correctanswer youranswer > /dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "The two outputs were exactly the same "
    else
        echo "$divider"
        echo "The two outputs were different "
        diff youranswer correctanswer
        echo "Do you wish to see the ouputs side-by-side?"
        select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
            case $yn in
                Yes)  echo "LEFT: Your Output   RIGHT: Solution Output"
                      sleep 1
                      vimdiff youranswer correctanswer
                      break;;
                 No)  exit;;
            esac
        done
    fi
done 3< "$file_input"
```

Modified so that the `read` command reads on file descriptor 3, leaving standard input available for the `select`, etc.

---

I don't know what you're doing that makes it fail.  I created two programs, `test1` and `test2`.  Initially, they were identical:

```
printf "%s\n" "$@"
```

Then I changed `test2` so it contained:

```
printf "%s\n" "1$@2"
```

With this data in `input.file`:

```
9 11 22 13
2 35 32 16
```

I ran the script `botched.sh`:

```
$ bash -x botched.sh input.file
+ '[' -f /etc/bashrc ']'
+ . /etc/bashrc
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ return
+ alias 'r=fc -e -'
+ your_path=./test1
+ test_path=./test2
+ file_input=input.file
+ read -r -u 3 contents
+ ./test2 9 11 22 13
+ ./test1 9 11 22 13
+ diff correctanswer youranswer
+ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
+ echo 'The two outputs were exactly the same '
The two outputs were exactly the same 
+ read -r -u 3 contents
+ ./test2 2 35 32 16
+ ./test1 2 35 32 16
+ diff correctanswer youranswer
+ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
+ echo 'The two outputs were exactly the same '
The two outputs were exactly the same 
+ read -r -u 3 contents
$
```

The outputs were recognized as identical, as you'd expect.  Then with the modified `test2`, I reran it:

```
$ bash -x botched.sh input.file
+ '[' -f /etc/bashrc ']'
+ . /etc/bashrc
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ return
+ alias 'r=fc -e -'
+ your_path=./test1
+ test_path=./test2
+ file_input=input.file
+ read -r -u 3 contents
+ ./test2 9 11 22 13
+ ./test1 9 11 22 13
+ diff correctanswer youranswer
+ '[' 1 -eq 0 ']'
+ echo ''

+ echo 'The two outputs were different '
The two outputs were different 
+ diff youranswer correctanswer
1c1
< 9
---
> 19
4c4
< 13
---
> 132
+ echo 'Do you wish to see the ouputs side-by-side?'
Do you wish to see the ouputs side-by-side?
+ select yn in '"Yes"' '"No"'
1) Yes
2) No
#? 1
+ case $yn in
+ echo 'LEFT: Your Output   RIGHT: Solution Output'
LEFT: Your Output   RIGHT: Solution Output
+ sleep 1
+ vimdiff youranswer correctanswer
2 files to edit
+ break
+ read -r -u 3 contents
+ ./test2 2 35 32 16
+ ./test1 2 35 32 16
+ diff correctanswer youranswer
+ '[' 1 -eq 0 ']'
+ echo ''

+ echo 'The two outputs were different '
The two outputs were different 
+ diff youranswer correctanswer
1c1
< 2
---
> 12
4c4
< 16
---
> 162
+ echo 'Do you wish to see the ouputs side-by-side?'
Do you wish to see the ouputs side-by-side?
+ select yn in '"Yes"' '"No"'
1) Yes
2) No
#? 2
+ case $yn in
+ exit
$
```

The `vimdiff` program did run and show the differences.

Note the basic debugging technique — running with `bash -x`.  It shows that the read is taking a single line of input with four numbers, and then those are passed to the surrogate programs `test1` and `test2`; then it takes a second line, and passes those to the surrogates programs.

Actual test code:

```
your_path=./test1 #../test/test
test_path=./test2 #../../public/test    
file_input="$1"
while read -r -u 3 contents
do
    # Display output of the test file
    "$test_path" $contents > correctanswer 2>&1
    # Display output of your file
    "$your_path" $contents > youranswer 2>&1
    # diff the solutions
    diff correctanswer youranswer > /dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "The two outputs were exactly the same "
    else
        echo "$divider"
        echo "The two outputs were different "
        diff youranswer correctanswer
        echo "Do you wish to see the ouputs side-by-side?"
        select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
            case $yn in
                Yes)  echo "LEFT: Your Output   RIGHT: Solution Output"
                      sleep 1
                      vimdiff youranswer correctanswer
                      break;;
                 No)  exit;;
            esac
        done
    fi
done 3< "$file_input"
```

Tested with Bash 3.2.51 on Mac OS X 10.9.2.

If it doesn't work for you, then you need to set up surrogate test programs, similar to mine, and show what you get from running `bash -x` on your script.  You should also identify the platform you're running on and the version of Bash you are running.

Comment: Yours is having the same problem as everyone else. Once I change it to this code, the program says usage problem not entering the right amount of inputs. I am running it like ./test testcase and in the file testcase has the digits 3 4 5 6 in line 1 5 6 7 8 in line 2 and it doesn't work the one I had up there works perfectly fine without being able to read multiple lines

Comment: I don't know what you're doing that makes it not work for you.  I've updated my answer with evidence it works for me, identifying what that means in terms of platform and version of Bash.  You'll need to provide comparable evidence of what is going wrong for you.

Comment: Using 4.1.11(2)-release

Comment: When I run it ./test testcase <-- the file with the numbers 11 9 42 57 on one line.
It gives me a usage error that I put on the program (invalid number of arguments) but when I go into the directory ./program 11 9 42 57 it works fine. The weird thing is that it worked perfectly fine when I didn't try to read multiple lines, the one up above works fine when the file is one 1 line

Comment: We can't debug your script if you don't show us the whole script.  There's no 'usage error' in the code in the question!  What number of arguments are you insisting on?  And you have far too many things called `test` kicking around.  You do realize that `test` is a shell built-in, don't you?  It is therefore generally best avoided as a script name because it wreaks havoc if you don't invoke it with an explicit pathname each time.  I've no idea whether your `../test/test` is the same as your `./test` program; it begins to sound as if it is.  And you've got `../../public/test` as another one.

Comment: Actually I got it working. Sorry about that your code works :)